# Is $d(i,j) = 1-\textrm{corr}(i,j)$ a metric?

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, correlation

I need to make sure that this function is a metric:

$d(i,j) = 1-\textrm{corr}(i,j)$

where $\textrm{corr}(x,y)$ is the *Pearson correlation coefficient* which ranges from $[-1,1]$. With this scaling I can satisfy the first three properties of a metric:

- $d(i,j)>0$
- $d(i,i)=0$
- $d(i,j)=d(j,i)$

but I'm not sure how to check the triangle inequality:

$d(i,k) \leq d(i,k)+d(j,k)$.

Should I employ some property of correlation coefficients?

Comment: something is missing here...did you check whether $d(i,j)=0$ iff $i=j$?

Comment: @Avitus Wasn't one direction done in the 2nd property?

Comment: yes, one direction is contained in the second property, you are right.The property in my comment above is stronger, however: btw @linello, is it true that $corr(i,j)=0$ iff $i=j$?

Comment: The triangle inequality also fails.

Comment: Try the triangle inequality with $i=(-1, 0, 1), \; j=(1, -1, 0), \; k=(-1, -1, 2)$

Answer (score 1):

For being a metric $d(i,j)=0$ must imply $i=j$. But if $i,j$ are linearly related then also $corr(i,j)=1$ and $d(i,j)=0$. So first you have to partition the space of random variables into disjoint equivalence classes where the equivalence relation would be defined as: $x\sim y$ if $x$ and $y$ are linearly related. In that case you need to define the function $d([i],[j])=1-corr(i,j)$, where $[k]$ is the equivalence class containing $k$. You can show that this function is also well-defined.

Now consider the regression of $i$ on $j$ and then $j$ on $k$. Let the regression equations be
$$i=a_{i,j}+\frac{r_{i,j}s_{j}}{s_{i}}j+\epsilon_{i,j}$$
$$j=a_{j,k}+\frac{r_{j,k}s_{k}}{s_{j}}k+\epsilon_{j,k}$$
where $r_{m,n}$ is the correlation between variables $m,n$ and $s_l$is the standard deviation of the variable $l$. Then one can show that $$\frac{r_{i,k}s_k}{s_i}=\frac{r_{i,j}s_j}{s_i}\frac{r_{j,k}s_k}{s_j}$$
Hence $corr(i,k)^2\leq corr(i,k)=corr(i,j)corr(j,k)\leq\frac{cor(i,j)^2+corr(j,k)^2}{2}\leq\frac{cor(i,j)+corr(j,k)}{2}$
So nothing can be told about triangle inequality.